# notepad++ regex find and replace html img source to remove subfolder string where img resides

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to notepad++ regex but I'm trying to find and replace all subfolder strings in a img src html code line with a single string.
example:

```
replace - img src="/image_location/image.png"
with    - img src="/images/image.png"
```

But whenever I try the following

```
find    - img src=(.*)/
replace - img src="images/
```

it replaces all the way to the backslash in the closing /a argument rather than the backslash in the image location url.

Any help would be huge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are "greedy" by default: a pattern like `img src=(.*)/` will match as many characters as it can, and will happily eat up as many slashes as it needs to before finding the final one.

If you only want to match up to the second slash, try using a regex like `img src=[^/]*/[^/]*/` to ensure that exactly two slashes get matched.

BTW: `/` is a "forward slash" or simply "slash." Only `\` is a "backslash."

Answer (score 0):

You would want your search pattern to look like this:

```
img src=".*/(.*\.*)"
```

which finds what follows`img src="<any chars>/` that has `<any chars> . <any chars>`

```
image.png
```

→ [example](http://regexr.com?37k4l)